# Effect of depth, topn in nutch crawl

Tags: nutch

I have always wondered what is the effect of depth and topn for a nutch crawl? For example, let's assume a depth of 100 and topn of 10000 ensures a full crawl, would changing the depth to 1000 affect the time taken for the crawl? So to crawl a unfamiliar website, is it ok to give a arbitrarily large depth and topn?

Thanks for the help,

Ananth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depth is number of hops from root and topn is maximum link to be fetched in each level. So AFAIK by increasing depth it will definitely increase time taken to crawl. Changing depth from 100 to 1000 should increase the crawling time very much.

Comment: Thanks CRS for the response. But i'm still not clear on one thing. If the website has a maximum depth of 100 i.e. i assume that following a link recursively, you don't get more than 100 links, would my giving any other value affect it. If so, how?

Comment: In that case I think it should not have any effect. 100 and 1000 should not make any difference.